# pdfbox embedding subset font for annotations - part 2

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdfbox, acrobat

I am creating a separate question, stemming from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137356/pdfbox-embedding-subset-font-for-annotations). The used code is almost the same. The reason is that the original problem was about subsetting a font with pdfbox, which I kind of dealt with. I got faced though with another problem, which is : the annotations, and how the fonts used in them are interpreted by particularly Acrobat Reader DC.

I tried different combinations of fonts and embedding options and got rather desperate. The fact is that I had a feeling that in particular the way these things are handled by the programs that interpret the PDF files is non-standard. I think I read somewhere that the annotations and the way they are displayed is on purpose non-standardized by the PDF format, to give freedom to the interpreters to handle them in their own way, since the main purpose of the annotations is the interaction with the user. TL;DR I cannot understand why Acrobat Reader DC doesn't like the annotations I have created and saved with PDFBOX. I even opened [a question](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/add-stamp-free-text-annotation-to-existing-document-inc-save-extract-embedded-font-warning-comment/m-p/11980610) on friendly and helpful Adobe's User Community forum. But as I expected, someone suggested me to better investigate this question with the PDFBOX team.

Everything is possible, but rather than writing a question on PDFBOX mailing list (I could never get used or understand the efficient use of the mailing lists btw), I want to open a question here because I hope that it could help others to understand the PDF format better.

I basically rephrase the above question from the Adobe's forums here: Here is [an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bxFU7aBZBlQRBv80ZEImZV0kdPilHOEu/view?usp=sharing) (Google Drive link) with FreeText annotations (but it seems to make no difference if I use Stamp annotations instead), it causes problems when open by Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (file) version 21.001.20149.37945 (I think this corresponds to April 16th '21 update). Specifically the problem happens when the Comments pane is opened by the user, either manually or automatically.

Manually:

[image: How to open Comments pane in Acrobat Reader DC manually via menu] [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJ529.png)

Automatically:

[image: How to set Comments pane to open automatically on document load in Acrobat Reader DC via Preferences] [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVEZn.png)

While experimenting, I also tried to unset the "Use local fonts" option in Preferences -> Page Display. I had the impression that maybe Acrobat Reader will be more eager to show the error message once it is not allowed to substitute the erroneously embedded fonts with the possible local fonts. I am not sure if this is true.

The error that I get is the infamous "Cannot extract the embedded font XXXXXX+SomeFontName" as seen in the below picture:

[image: Adobe Acrobat Reader DC error when the Comments pane is open with the example document] [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVOlW.png)

The same problems happen also if I use full font embed (subsetting option set to false when using PDType0Font.load). I also tried to embed OpenSans font instead of LiberationSans, also tried to manually convert LiberationSans to a TTF font with fewer glyphs using FontForge, even tried to use Windows ARIALN.TTF, thinking that maybe the font is the problem. All cause the same behavior in Acrobat Reader DC. I have also tried to run Acrobat Reader 2019 Pro Preflight on the document and in the profile that scans the document for the possible font inconsistencies, it reports no errors.

Of course, when I use e.g. PDType1Font.HELVETICA instead of custom TTF font, I do not get the above errors. But I cannot use it because it does not contain the glyphs for the Unicode characters that I use. Does anybody have a better idea?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**: to make myself clear - the error does not appear ALWAYS. it appears on some machines constantly (e.g. I am using Windows 7 64-bit with latest Acrobat Reader DC installed to reproduce it fairly well), while on my Windows 10 64-bit with the same version of Acrobat Reader DC it sometimes appears, and sometimes not - I haven't figured out why or in what cases.. - which makes me think - but no - I checked that too - the font I am using opens up alright on the machine where the problem is fairly constant)

**UPDATE**: at my wits ends again, I created a blank page with Apache OpenOffice, exported it to PDF, opened it with Acrobat Reader DC (last version), added a FreeTextTypewriter annotation (View -> Tools -> Comment -> Open) with 4 greek letters in ArialNarrow font, saved it, reopened it with Acrobat Reader DC, and it gives me the same error (cannot extract the embedded font...).. So this could be the Reader problem? But they made this so difficult to diagnose.. [Here is the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_um6miR-VqWJC1shlsAXebOnuItVfS6g/view?usp=sharing), but I do not expect it to show errors on other machines. It's one of those moments that you start to believe in magic and the power of prayer (and a good sleep)

**UPDATE 30/04/2021**
So, to sum things up, I haven't come with a solution yet, but I came up with three files created with PDFBOX, OpenPDF (iText5 fork) and Acrobat Reader DC itself (can append annotations and save - just adding a simple Text box with greek text through Comment pane) - and they all issue the above error message, when open by Acrobat Reader DC. I have posted details in the Acrboat Reader forum [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/add-stamp-free-text-annotation-to-existing-document-inc-save-extract-embedded-font-warning-comment/td-p/11980066) (same link as in comment)

I have added the code that I used to create the OpenPDF example file [here](https://github.com/hello-earth-gh/grumpy-hellcat/blob/master/grumpy-hellcat/src/main/java/pub/hello/earth/grumpy/hellcat/openpdf/PDFServiceOpenPDFTest.java) and the example 3 files are in the same repository [here](https://github.com/hello-earth-gh/grumpy-hellcat/tree/master/grumpy-hellcat/src/main/resources/examples/pdfannot)

Comment: It would be interesting to have a file where it happens and one where it doesn't happen. Preferably with one annotation only. The next step would be to look at both in PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr :) thanks for PDFDebugger hint - never heard of it - neither about the host of those other tools. I am playing around with the files, it seems that I am doing something wrong with the encoding of the text I am actually outputting with showText. I have created some annotations using Acrobat Reader and saved them and am inspecting them now. The actual contents of the content stream for the annotation there is done with a series of commands like <0209> Tj , while the content stream that I see from output with showText is like (...some squares) Tj

Comment: That doesn't mean much, there are several ways to do the same thing in PDF. And the text in the content stream doesn't have to be readable.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr indeed, it seems to not be the case - as the file I just modified with AAR DC itself seems to present the same problem (I have updated the question) (although I created the blank page I subsequently modified with OpenOffice... the problem seems so random and there are so many possible causes - the worst case scenario for me would be to transliterate, or use some kind of single-byte encoding / font...)

Comment: I got a warning `The TrueType font MXCCWK+ArialNarrow does not contain a 'cmap' table`. Don't know if this is relevant for Adobe.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am sorry I am so late on this, ... where exactly did you see this error about missing cmap table? I tried to look through the code of Fontbox (loadFont() and subset() functions) but really it was too much for me. I have the feeling though that PDFBOX and FONTBOX do their job correctly. I have posted an update to Acrobat Reader DC forum. I will also post a summary of what I did in the above question too... https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/add-stamp-free-text-annotation-to-existing-document-inc-save-extract-embedded-font-warning-comment/td-p/11980066

Comment: Sorry I see now that this log message is only in my own development version. It's only relevant for text extraction. And it's done on purpose because that information is available elsewhere in the PDF.