# pdfbox adding annotation to certified document with existing signature

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, digital-signature

and thanks for taking a look at this question.
I have been struggling with a sudden issue that came to my attention only recently.

**TL;DR**

When adding annotations to a specific document that contains a valid digital signature, the existing signature becomes invalid, even though the save is incremental and no problems were observed for other similar documents with valid signatures. The only way I could reproduce this behaviour was to add Certification while signing that restricts editing to only form fill-in, commenting and annotations (should be okay). Still, adding annotations afterwards the same way invalidates the signature.

**Question:**

1. Does making a PDF document "Certified" (actually I am kind of mixed up about what this means technically) effectively prohibits its being modified by specific annotations, even when it specifies that annotations are allowed?
2. Do I make some specific mistake in the way I add annotations, resulting in the above error?
3. When I open a document that was specifically created by `jSignPDF` with a certain Certificate Level, `Acrobat Reader` shows the following icon in the Signatures bar:

[image: Certification level icon]

What attribute does `Acrobat Reader` use to show this? Is there a way to effectively apply certification level without resulting in `Acrobat Reader` diplaying this icon? I am asking this because I have documents that display the same behavior (see below), but do not show this specific "seal" sign.

**Scenario:**

There is an existing application that routinely adds stamp annotations to existing PDF documents which are not usually digitally signed, or are signed by a known internal application. The resulting PDF with added annotations is saved incrementally, and when opened by Acrobat Reader, shows a warning saying that there were changes applied to the document after the signature, which is still valid.

[image: example_usual]

At some point the above application was fed with a PDF that was externally signed. The application added annotations, but they broke the validity of the existing signature. Unfortunately I am not at liberty to publish the document itself, but the picture shown by `Acrobat Reader` is as follows:

[image: example_signature_invalid]

I have tried various ways to reproduce this issue with a test document of my own creation. Up to now I have tried changing the PDF version (tried `1.4`, `1.6`, `1.7`), saving it as `Tagged`, adding `LTV` information (`OCSP` & `CRL`), and marking it as Certified, allowing form fill-in, commenting and annotations.

The tools I have used for the above tests are `LibreOffice 7.5.3.2` (Export As PDF), `qpdf` for changing PDF version from 1.6 to 1.7, `jSignPDF 2.2.0` (for signing with or without Certification, with or without LTV information, changing hash algorithm from `SHA1` to `SHA256`). Up to now the only way I was able to reproduce the issue was to create a document with Certification - even though the Certification specifies that annotations are allowed, it seems that the way I am adding them breaks something. I have checked the binary content of the file and the save indeed seems to have been done incrementally.

`jSignPDF` has the following interface to specify the level of Certification:
[image: jsignpdf UI]

I have created a test program that I used for the above tests and you can get the code [here](https://github.com/hello-earth-gh/grumpy-hellcat/tree/master/grumpy-hellcat). The specific file of interest is [this one](https://github.com/hello-earth-gh/grumpy-hellcat/blob/master/grumpy-hellcat/src/main/java/pub/hello/earth/grumpy/hellcat/pdfbox/PdfBoxAnnotationsBrokenSignatureScenario.java) and it calls a service which approximately does the following (I tried to rewrite it and put everything in a single block of code for clarity - but I don't expect it to run as is):

```java
...
PDPage page = pddoc.getPage(0);
List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();

// prefer rubber stamp because it does not require RC (rich content) to be defined and Acrobat Reader DC doesn't try to modify the document to create its own RC representation
PDAnnotationRubberStamp t = new PDAnnotationRubberStamp();

t.setAnnotationName(name); // might play important role
t.setPrinted(true); // always visible
t.setReadOnly(true); // does not interact with user
t.setContents(text);
t.setHidden(false);
t.setInvisible(false);
t.setLocked(true);

t.setPage(page);
t.setLockedContents(true);

PDFont font = null;
try ( InputStream fs = PDFService.class.getResourceAsStream("/static/fonts/LiberationSans-Bold.ttf")) {
    ret = PDType0Font.load(pddoc, fs, true);
    // PDFBOX will warn, but we ignore this warning according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67137356/pdfbox-embedding-subset-font-for-annotations
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Could not load font : " + ex.getMessage());
}

font.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
page.getResources().add(font);
page.getResources().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
page.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

subsetFonts.add(font); // should be subset once all annotations for a page have been added

PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x, y, 100, 100);
t.setRectangle(rect);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
t.setCreationDate(c);
t.setModifiedDate(c);

PDAppearanceDictionary ap = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
PDAppearanceStream aps = new PDAppearanceStream(document);
PDAppearanceContentStream apsContent = null;

PDRectangle rect = ann.getRectangle();
rect = new PDRectangle(0, 0, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight()); // need to be relative - this is mega important because otherwise it appears as if nothing is printed
aps.setBBox(rect); // set bounding box to the dimensions of the annotation itself

// in case of multiple lines, we want to start from the highest line
float initialY = rect.getHeight() - _fontSize;

// embed our unicode font (NB: yes, this needs to be done otherwise aps.getResources() == null which will cause NPE later during setFont)
PDResources res = new PDResources();
aps.setResources(res);

try {
    // draw directly on the XObject's content stream
    apsContent = new PDAppearanceContentStream(aps);
    apsContent.beginText();
    apsContent.setFont(font, _fontSize); // PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD would work if we didn't have possible greek characters
    apsContent.newLineAtOffset(0, initialY);
    apsContent.showText(ann.getContents());
    apsContent.endText();
} 
finally {
    if (apsContent != null) {
        try { apsContent.close(); } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); }
    }
}

aps.getResources().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
aps.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

ap.setNormalAppearance(aps);
ap.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
t.setAppearance(ap);

annotations.add(t);
page.setAnnotations(annotations);

t.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
page.getResources().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
page.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
pddoc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
pddoc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

if (font.willBeSubset()) {
    font.subset();
    font.getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true); // corresponsing page resources should also be set to be updated - but we do it already in addAnnotation            
}

pddoc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
pddoc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

pddoc.saveIncremental(baos);
...
```

Thank you all...

**EDIT:**
I have added [here](https://github.com/hello-earth-gh/grumpy-hellcat/tree/master/grumpy-hellcat/src/main/resources/pdfbox_sample_word) some test files. After some trial and error I came to the following conclusions:

When I create simple PDF files by exporting them from LibreOffice 7.2, then sign them with jSignPDF, choosing Certification Level = "Not certified", and later annotate them with the above procedure, things work as expected, existing signature still shows as valid, with the remark that there were changes made after the signature (the added annotations). Alright by me.

When I create PDF files by exporting them from Microsoft Word 2016/2019 documents, no matter how simple, they are significantly larger than PDFs produced by e.g. LibreOffice 7.2/7.5. After being signed by jSignPDF with the same way and annotated with the same above procedure, the existing signature shows as invalid, as in the above screenshots. I wonder - what is the problem that causes this failure - I guess it is that there is something that Acrobat Reader doesn't like and tries to change the contents on-the-run, that results in in-memory document corruption and the error message. I am trying to find a safe guideline to give to people using this way of producing their PDFs so that they would work with the above code later..

Even when I create files with LibreOffice as in the first case, when I sign them with jSignPDF, choosing Certification Level = "Form filling and annotations allowed", subsequent annotating of these files causes the signature to show as invalid. Is this a problem with how jSignPDF adds the signature?

Thanks....

Comment: The screenshot of the problem file shows that it is not certified, its signature is an approval signature. Thus, your looking for information about certification signatures likely won't help you here at all. The most important part of the screen shot actually is the warning "1 Page(s) modified" because that indicates that Adobe Acrobat sees more changes than the allowed addition of annotations. This might be caused by your code actually applying such disallowed changes (a quick glance at your code makes me assume that is not the case), or some JavaScript in the PDF applying some changes, or...

Comment: ... or an error in the PDF making Adobe Acrobat repair the file under the hood and so invalidating the signature. As you cannot share the PDF in question, I cannot tell which of these options it is...

Comment: thank you very much, @mkl - i will try and ask for a proper public test file and attach it here when I get it. meanwhile I will keep searching and will post anything more I find. Thanks for the pointers and your being here for all of us.

Comment: @mkl I have added some samples and made an edit towards the end of my question - is there a chance you took a look on paricularly FAILURE_simple_test_libre72_cerified_signed_annotated.pdf and FAILURE_simple_test_word2016_not_certified_standard_size_signed_annotated.pdf - have any idea why their signatures are shown as invalid? I explain in the edit how I produced them. Thanks and sorry for the hassle.

Comment: as per mkl's answer below, I had to make sure that the calls to `setNeedToBeUpdated` for the following objects should NOT be made : `page.getResources().getCOSObject()` , `page.getCOSObject()`. The document catalog still has to be marked for change : `pddoc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);` , `pddoc.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().setNeedToBeUpdated(true);`

Comment: *"as per mkl's answer below, I had to make sure that the calls to `setNeedToBeUpdated` for the following objects should NOT be made : `page.getResources().getCOSObject() , page.getCOSObject()`"* - Beware, it may not be that simple, you want to add an annotation after all. So if the **Annots** array of the page is a direct object, you have to mark the page dictionary. Nonetheless, you have to make sure that the page resources are not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the example files the problem became clear - your code changes the page resources and, therefore, the page as far as Adobe Acrobat is concerned, invalidating the signature. (It's actually quite visible in the code you posted but one easily overlooks something like that.)

But your code does not mark all objects from the page to the font resources as updated, you forgot the **Font** dictionary in the **Resources** dictionary.

In case of the MS Word generated PDFs the extra fonts were added to the output nonetheless as the resources in the page are direct objects. LibreOffice, on the other hand, uses indirect object hierarchies for the resources. Thus, the extra fonts were not added to the resulting PDF and, consequentially, Adobe Acrobat did not find any changes to the (static) page content.

Essentially, therefore, those fonts must not be in the page resources when you store your incremental update.

I don't know whether it would make sense to have them there temporarily until you call their `subset` methods, but in the end the page resources must not be changed in a signed PDF.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough. you make the world a better place. thanks.